# Get Raw XML from java web service call in .NET

Tags: java, .net, service, client

I am calling a Java web service using a .NET client, the return message is badly formatted since the deserialzation process throws an exception.
Is there a way to view the raw xml data being returned by the web service in the .NET Client.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). It is a great tool that allows you to call web services and inspect the generated XML.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http sniffing software that sit between your clients and the server. Search for http sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fiddler(http://fiddler2.com/) to intercept the inbound and outbound web-service calls from your computer..

Run Fiddler.. Then use your .NET client or Browser to invoke the web-service.. In fiddler you can see the web-service endpoint on left hand side.. Click on that to view request and response on the right hand side..

[image: Here is an screenshot of the Fiddler UI..]